# CSS: make div slide over another div (i.e., use a div as background)

Tags: html, css, scroll, overlay

I have a div that acts as the page background and other divs are showing over it.

However when the user scrolls, the background div scrolls too. I'd like it to be fixed while the content div scrolls over it.

This is my actual code:

```
#background {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
}
#content {
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Can this be done? Thank you

Comment: can You run the code in fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `position: fixed` you need to also specify values for the position of the element.

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8pt71b9/) demonstrating this:

HTML:

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="content">
    This is the content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/metal_lines_stripes_light_shiny_silver_18401_1920x1080.jpg);
}
#content {
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    width: 100%;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 300%;
    height: 400%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that by background div is not an image, but a map from Google Maps. So i can't set the background image.

Comment: @FrCr You didn't say so in the question. So how do you reference that map? Why can't you simply add an img tag to the background div or similar? The background-image just served as an example. It is the div that is fixed, that  is what you asked.

Comment: you're right, I just figured out that this didn't work for me because of the framework I am using, not for an issue in the code itself. Now I fixed it thanks to your code and some modification required by the framework. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can see the demo page:

```
body, html, main {
    /* important */
    height: 100%;
}

.cd-fixed-bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
  background-image: url("http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4056/4228935406_93ff14c971.jpg");
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-2 {
  background-image: url("http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4056/4228935406_93ff14c971.jpg");
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-3 {
  background-image: url("http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4056/4228935406_93ff14c971.jpg");
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-4 {
  background-image: url("http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4056/4228935406_93ff14c971.jpg");
}

.cd-scrolling-bg {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

[HERE MY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/ttdz71p3/)

Comment: Would be helpful if you explained what you did in addition to the code dump

Comment: The problem is that by background div is not an image, but a map from Google Maps. So i can't set the background image.